# How to use setinverval in component use many times?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

My 'Monster' component did the same action each 300ms.
So here is how it does :

```
componentDidMount(){  
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
       this.handleMove(this.state.direction)
    }, 300);
}
```

But this component is used many times so I have many setinterval and everything is slow :

```
<Monster id="monster1" position={[0,360]} direction='EAST' />
<Monster id="monster2" position={[240,280]} direction='SOUTH' />
<Monster id="monster3" position={[400,480]} direction='WEST' />
<Monster id="monster4" position={[480,560]} direction='SOUTH' />
<Monster id="monster5" position={[480,80]} direction='SOUTH' />
<Monster id="monster6" position={[480,400]} direction='EAST' />
<Monster id="monster7" position={[640,320]} direction='WEST' />
<Monster id="monster7" position={[960,480]} direction='SOUTH' />
```

Is there a solution to call just one setinterval who make my component did the same action each 300ms with redux or something else ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: not sure I understand your question correctly, do you want to `setInterveal()` in only 1 Monster Component?

Comment: I assume you wanted to have a `static` or `shared` `setInterval` function, which is shared among all `Monster` instances. If my assumption is correct, you can't get such function, at least in your case. See the `func` argument of `setInterval( func, interval)`, in your case, it should be various between different `Monster` instances, as `this.state.direction` may be various.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez no, every component has a setinterval who make him move

Comment: @Wenbo yes it's what I want. But i don't know if it's the better solution.
I want each monster component move every 300ms but don't know how to do that without having many setinterval.
I'll take a look at that thanks

Comment: @YannSAINTY, I recommend you write a `move` function inside `Monster`, and then a `setInterval` in a management class or controller, in the `setInterval`, call `move` of all instances of `Monster`. This may be a proper solution to your question.

Comment: @Wenbo it what I think too, but I just begin with React so I don't really know how to do that. But you confirm my idea is good so I'll try to do things in this direction. 
Because I think it's what I do. But it's very slow because the move function is called each 300ms in each Monster. So if I have 10 monsters 10 setinterval are called each 300ms..
Thanks !

Comment: @Wenbo I understand what you say, but don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I tried something with static function but it doesn't work :

Parent :

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
       Monster.moveFromWorld()
   }, 300);
}
```

Monster.js :

```
static moveFromWorld(){
    this.handleMove(this.state.direction)
}

handleMove(direction){
   switch(direction){
      case 'WEST':
          return this.attemptMove('WEST')
      case 'EAST':
          return this.attemptMove('EAST')
      case 'NORTH':
          return this.attemptMove('NORTH')
      case 'SOUTH':
           return this.attemptMove('SOUTH')
      default:
   }
}
```

And I got :TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined
And if I remove this.state.direction I got :TypeError: this.handleMove is not a function

So I have two problems :
- Calling my function
- Giving here a parameter

Thanks
 - List item